# Can Fokker-Planck operator be turned into a hermitian operator?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, operators, stochastic-processes, non-equilibrium

We know that [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) can be written as(with proper boundary and initial condition)
$$
\frac{\partial  p(v,t)}{\partial t} = Lp(v,t)
$$
where $L$ is known as the Fokker-Planck operator and for our case let's say it is given by $$ L = 1 + v\frac{\partial}{\partial  v} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial  v^2} $$ and it is in general neither hermitian nor anti-hermitian but rather mixed. Let's say the stationary state of this equation is given by $$p^{st}(v). $$ $L$ can be converted into a hermitian operator by the following transformation,
$$
 L^{new} = (p^{st}(v))^\frac{-1}{2}*L*(p^{st}(v))^\frac{1}{2}
$$
How this last line can be understood? I didn't understand how this works and what sort of transformation is this?

Comment: You expect the reader to read your reference for you so you won’t need to define *L* ?

Comment: Sorry for not writing the form of L. I have edited the question, I hope this helps now.